# Remove multi match in regex

Tags: regex

I want to make a redirection on an url :
`/XX/YY/ZZ%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E` => `/XX/YY/ZZ`

I don't find the good regex to remove multi match "%3E" at the end of the url.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: What language/environment are we talking? (e.g. bash, Python)

Comment: I'm using ruby !

Comment: what is the need to use regex for that if it is always %3E you want to remove? Can you not just string-"replace" it (with an empty string)?

Comment: You should perhaps add the tag `ruby` to your question. See also my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (for actual URLs with the indicated kind of suffix):

```
x = "https://www.test.com/XX/YY/ZZ%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E%3E"
s.gsub(/(%3E)+$/,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this pattern:**

```
\/[\w]{2}
```

You can test it [online](http://rubular.com)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Human and Drux !

You really helped me to find the solution :

> r301   %r{^/XX/([\w\/]*)(%3E)+$}, '/XX/$1'